# why does "a();function a(){}" work in javascript? but most of the other dynamic language do not

Tags: javascript, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ambiguous function declaration in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072685/ambiguous-function-declaration-in-javascript)

above does work in nodejs. I am wondering about the underlying difference of javascript and python/ruby handling this case.

Answer (score 4):

Because in JavaScript, *[[FunctionDeclaration]]s* are hoisted (including initialization) to the top of the current lexical scope. So you can call them anywhere within the lexical scope (even "before" they're "defined").

Feel free to check the spec if you're interested in the exact process: http://es5.github.com/#x13

Comment: +1 for actually understanding hoisting. It's amazing how many people just don't get that.

Comment: However this only applies to functions declared as `function foo() {}`, as opposed to those declared as `foo = function() {}`

Comment: @Kolink is correct, function expressions are hoisted, but only the variable definition (where applicable), the instantiation of the function is *not* hoisted as it is with function declarations.